# How To Create Record with many2one, many2many data in JAVA ODOO XMLRPC

Tags: java, odoo

**Here is my function for creating record with Mpa Data**
This function take as input the *model name* and the *data* to create record.

**My data:** *{"categ_id":[1,"All"],"website_meta_keywords":false,"available_in_pos":true}*

**My error:** *psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: ERREUR:  syntaxe en entrée invalide pour l'entier : « All »
LINE 1: ...w() at time zone 'UTC'), true, true, 0.0, ARRAY[1,'All'], 'A...*

```
public Integer createRecord (String modelName, Map data) {
    Integer recordId = -1;
    try {
        client.setConfig(objectConfig);
        recordId = (Integer) client.execute("execute_kw", asList(
                this.database, this.uid, this.password,
                modelName, "create",
                asList(
                       data
                )
        ));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("[OdooXmlRpc.createRecord] Exception when creating record in " + modelName + ". Details: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return recordId;
}
```

Comment: can I ask which API or SDK you're using for `Odoo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo raised that error because of the value of `categ_id`, the value of a Many2one field should be an existing record ID (of type integer, which can also be passed as a string).

Use a special [commands](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L3252) format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the x2many fields.

***Example (`order_line` field value):***

```java
Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(0, 0, new HashMap() {{ put("product_id", product_id); ...}} ))
```

Comment: what mean the two zero in the array please?

Comment: The first zero mean that you want to add a new record and as you can find in the source code documentation, **values marked as `_` in the list above are ignored and can be anything, generally `0` or `False`** and this is why I put the second zero. Please check the link in my answer.